# Simple mysql insert occasionally taking over 300 seconds

Tags: mysql, aws

I have a super simple insert query, something like

```
insert INTO `table_a` (`choice`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Which inserts one integer (1 to 10) and 2 time stamps. 99.9% of time its a normal sub 10 ms query, but occasionally it goes up to over 300 seconds.
The server at those times is not under heavy load. 
We use AWS RDS instance for the DB and the logs there look fine.

Any ideas why this might happen?

The create table script:

```
CREATE TABLE multiple_choice_answers` (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  choice tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3875644
          DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The table has 3853275 rows.

We are using InnoDB and no DB snapshots or dumps were taken at that times. I was thinking it might be a deadlock, but it makes no sence since none of those 3 columns are used as foreign key for any other tables.

Comment: note a deadlock isn't the same as a lockwait. Try to grab a 'SHOW PROCESSLIST' / 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS' at the time of waiting.